# LEFT OUTER JOIN cant group column and returns duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, grouping

I have simplified my question and tidied up the example. Sorry for the confusion.

I have two tables

kpi_index and audit_results

the kpi_index contains 8 unique sor_code's for subcategory 'C1'
the audit_results contains records with audits 
kpi_index is joined via INDEX field to sor_code kpi_index field

I need the result to show 'All' 8 sor_codes and the number of audits, audits that complied and the percentage pass, per sor_code, however, if there are no results for any sor_code, show a NULL or '0' against the sor_code.

I came up with this query, but for some reason I get duplicate sor_codes if there is a result found i.e. values in the audit_results e.g. C1.TAM and C1.TOM values are returned from the audit_results table and I therefore need to not show a null from the kpi_index matching sor_code/record.

My goal is to show all the sor_codes available from the kpi_index and populate those sor_codes where matches are found in the joined audit_results table and replace the matching null line with the populated 'audited/complied/percentage' values - there should be no duplicate sor_code with a null value if a matching sor_code was found in the audit_results.

Thanks

```
sor_code    Spec. Code  audits  complied    percentage  contractor
C1.SNM  C1  0   null    null    null
C1.SSM  C1  0   null    null    null
C1.TAM  C1  0   null    null    null
C1.TAM  C1  186 151 81% South
C1.TIM  C1  0   null    null    null
C1.TNM  C1  0   null    null    null
C1.TOM  C1  0   null    null    null
C1.TOM  C1  41  40  98% South

SELECT DISTINCT
      kpi_index.sor_code,
      kpi_index.`Spec. Code`,
      COUNT(audit_results.compliance) AS audits,
      SUM(audit_results.compliance) AS complied,
      CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(audit_results.compliance) / COUNT(kpi_index.sor_code) * 100, 0), '%') AS percentage,
      audit_results.contractor
    FROM kpi_index
      LEFT OUTER JOIN audit_results
        ON kpi_index.`INDEX` = audit_results.kpi_index
    WHERE audit_results.contractor = 'South'
    OR auit_results.contractor IS NULL
    GROUP BY kpi_index.sor_code,
             audit_results.contractor
    HAVING kpi_index.`Spec. Code` = 'C1'
    ORDER BY kpi_index.sor_code
```

Comment: You probably want to move `audit_results.contractor = 'south'` into the join condition. Get rid of the rest of the `where` clause entirely. The rest of what you're doing with `having` and the subquery and the outer `group by` doesn't appear to make much sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    kpi_index.sor_code,
    min(kpi_index.`Spec. Code`) AS spec_code,
    COUNT(audit_results.compliance) AS audits,
    SUM(audit_results.compliance) AS complied,
    CONCAT(ROUND(
        SUM(audit_results.compliance) * 100.00
            / COUNT(kpi_index.sor_code),
        0), '%') AS percentage,
    MIN(audit_results.contractor) AS contractor
FROM
    kpi_index
    LEFT OUTER JOIN audit_results
        ON kpi_index.`INDEX` = audit_results.kpi_index
           AND audit_results.contractor = 'South'
WHERE kpi_index.`Spec. Code` = 'C1'
GROUP BY kpi_index.sor_code
ORDER BY kpi_index.sor_code
```

1. `DISTINCT` is not necessary. When you're including all the `GROUP BY` columns the results are already distinct.
2. The main problem you were having was with the attempt to filter
   your join to only rows with `contractor = 'South'`. When you use an
   outer join you have to be careful with `WHERE` clause conditions
   because the joins are logically completed first and then the conditions are  applied afterward. When your join had matched only on contractors of a different name then none of your rows matched the `is null` or `= 'South'` tests.
3. The condition in the `HAVING` really belongs in the `WHERE`
   clause. It actually doesn't strictly make sense even though MySQL
   appears to accept it.
4. I've removed the extra grouping on `contractor` preferring to use
   `MIN()` in the `SELECT` list instead. Ultimately it should be
   redundant if my presumption that `contractor` is not nullable is
   correct.

Comment: Thank you so much Shawn! I had two major problems to solve and I have spent a few days trying to nut both of them out and under a lot of stress - I am working the weekend to save my job - I have never used SQL before so all new to me. Thank you very much for the speedy response and correct answer. I should have reached out to stackoverflow before now. Have a great weekend. I am so grateful for people like yourselves willing to help others just get ahead. Thank you!

Comment: @HairyMaclary I've had a few stressful weekends. Looks like maybe you got both your questions answered so hopefully you can relax for a day.